# Clearing default user on the web and in designer?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have two SharePoint 2013 sites.     Site1 and Site2.   I have two IDs.   MyID and TestID.

MyID is the ID I also use to log into Windows 7.

I used TestID to do some testing on Site2.    Now no matter what I do, TestId is the default ID for Site2.  I tried logging in as a different user using MyID but when I come back to my site it goes back to TestID as the default.

What is worse is that I cannot get into Site2 in designer.  It never prompts me to login.   I am thinking it is using TestID to sign into my site.    If I get into Site1, I am being asked to login with the default user as TestID but I am given the option to use another ID.   I use MyID and I get in.   I can then also get into Site2.

I tried clearing cache as found here

http://benprins.wordpress.com/2013/09/03/sharepoint-designer-clearing-the-cache/

but that was no help.  Any idea how to straighten this mess out?

We are still using IE8.   Maybe part of the issue.

We are using SharePoint 2013 foundation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with IE8. If you still didn't, try with compatibility view.
For my testing with different users anyway it is better to use different browser. I am using IE, Chrome and Firefox with 3 different accounts exactly for this reason.

Comment: But what about the Designer issue?  Or could it be IE8 affecting it too?  I sure wish we would upgrade.

I was just upgraded to Win 7, 2 days ago. :)

Comment: Happy if you solved with this. Anyway "officially" IE8 is not compatible with SP 2013, even common users can have a lot of issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed the issue with MyID on the web.  I switched users, used MyID to login then check Remember My Credentails.    That seemed to fix it.

Also seems to have fixed the Designer issue.